# How to have non-grouping JFrames within the same application?

Tags: java, windows, swing, jframe, taskbar

I'm creating a new JFrame from within an already running JFrame. Both frames are separate applications, but in this case, the second application gets a "plugin handle" of the first application instead of using its default stuff. For some operations in the second app, a callback is made to the first app to know what to do/display.

This way, the second application can be reused by many other applications. It is and will NOT be possible to manually start some java.exe command to achieve a real separate process.

Now, to emphasize that the second JFrame is another application, I want the taskbar entry to not be grouped together with the entry that was already there for the first JFrame. So basically this is a Windows 7 issue in combination with Java.

The icons on the taskbar are grouped together by default, there is enough space for them to be displayed separately but they simply don't.

How can I display the JFrame's icons separately on the taskbar? I can't find anything on JFrame that does what I want.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  *"..a callback is made to the first app to know what to do/display."*  You might have coded these as separate applications, but your description makes it seem there should only be one app.

Comment: How can I display the JFrame's icons separately on the taskbar?, do you meaning SystemTray

Comment: @AndrewThompson Nope, definately not. The number of possible callbacks is 5 and are "small". I already saw your link before you posted. Both apps already exist, all I have to do is implement some interfaces to connect them and it's already working. The apps are totally different, period.

Comment: @mKorbel No, not the System tray. The Taskbar itself.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I didn't write the apps myself but managed to connect them in 1 day. The second app is designed to be reusable so please don't try to know better. Can you please help me on the actual question, we are off track here.

Comment: *"How can I display the JFrame's icons separately on the taskbar?"*  This is 'futzing'.  I have no intention of attempting to help you achieve it.  The only reason I entered the 1st comment is so that anyone who (unfortunately) stumbles upon this thread might be warned.  And with that, I'm out of here.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Can't see how you can call this futzing as separate apps, which of course are displayed in separate frames, need separate taskbar entries. But OK

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed as unclear; it's a legitimate question in a Windows context, and native applications can certainly do exactly this.  (Whether it's possible from Java, I have no idea.)  More information available here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/08/20/10341464.aspx